# Is it possible to create triggered/scheduled web jobs automatically after an insert is done in the Azure Table?

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk, azure-webjobs-triggered

We have a requirement where we want to create a scheduled web job to call an API and process some data at the 12:00 AM every night. However, each of the job needs to be triggered at 12:00 AM of specific time-zone, to which the record in the table belongs.

Is it possible to automate the creation of web job with scheduled time, after an entry is done in the table? The time zone information along with other inputs, required by the API, will be in the table record. As far as I have googled, I am not able to find if it is possible to automate the creation of web job after an event.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the executable ready as a zip you can upload that zip to your App Service Web App as a Webjob using the [Webjobs API](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs-API#upload-a-triggered-job-as-zip).